# Keeping specific terms in Mathematica output

Tags: simplifying-expressions, expression-manipulation

Update: After solving an equation I came up with a complicated expression, is it possible to only keep some specific terms of an expression ?
As an example, if the expression is:

[image]

How can I keep only those terms that contain \[CapitalDelta] ? 
(In the output I expect to see an expanded form of the above expr only with terms that contain \[CapitalDelta])

Answer (score 2):

```
expr = -Δ^2 - 3 ga^2 - gb^2 - Δ δa + δa^2 + Δ δb + δa δb + δb^2;
expr2 = -(Δ^2 - 3 ga^2 - gb^2)^2 - Δ δa + δa^2 + Δ δb + δa δb + δb^2 ;
expr3=(2 + Δ g + 9 Δ g^2 - 3 Δ^2 δa + 3 g^2 δa- 
   18 g^2 δa Sqrt[(4 (-Δ^2 - 3 g^3 - 3 g +Δ δa - δa + Δ δb+ δb δa - δa)^3)])^(1/3) ;
```

A combination of [`Replace`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Replace.html), [`DeleteCases`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DeleteCases.html) and [`FreeQ`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FreeQ.html) can be used to modify the sub-expressions $x_1 + \cdots + x_n$ at the desired level:

```
Replace[Expand @ expr, p_Plus:> DeleteCases[p, _?(FreeQ[Δ])], All]
```

> -Δ^2 - Δ δa + Δ δb

```
Replace[Expand @ expr2, p_Plus:> DeleteCases[p, _?(FreeQ[Δ])], All]
```

> 6 ga^2 Δ^2 + 2 gb^2 Δ^2 - Δ^4 - Δ δa + Δ δb

```
Replace[Expand @ expr3, p_Plus:> DeleteCases[p, _?(FreeQ[Δ])], All]
```

> (g Δ + 9 g^2 Δ - 3 Δ^2 δa - 36 g^2 δa Sqrt[(-Δ^2 + Δ δa)^3])^(1/3)

```
TeXForm @ %
```

> $\small \sqrt[3]{-3 \Delta ^2 \text{$\delta $a}-36 \text{$\delta $a} g^2 \sqrt{\left(\Delta  \text{$\delta $a}-\Delta
>    ^2\right)^3}+9 \Delta  g^2+\Delta  g}$

Change `All` to `{0,1}` to keep the expression inside `Sqrt` intact:

```
Replace[Expand @ expr3, p_Plus:> DeleteCases[p,_?(FreeQ[Δ])], {0, 1}]
```

> (g Δ + 9 g^2 Δ - 3 Δ^2 δa - 36 g^2 δa Sqrt[(-3 g - 3 g^3 - Δ^2 - 2 δa + Δ δa + δbδa + Δ δb)^3])^(1/3)

```
TeXForm @ %
```

> $\small\sqrt[3]{-3 \Delta ^2 \text{$\delta $a}+9 \Delta  g^2-36 \text{$\delta $a} g^2 \sqrt{\left(-\Delta ^2+\Delta 
>    \text{$\delta $a}+\Delta  \text{$\delta $b}-2 \text{$\delta $a}+\text{$\delta $b$\delta $a}-3 g^3-3
>    g\right)^3}+\Delta  g}$

Comment: Or `Select[expr, !FreeQ[#, Δ]&]` or `Total@Cases[expr, _?(!FreeQ[#, Δ]&)]`

Comment: @kglr Thanks, however, if I use a more complicatedterm it does not work. Not sure what is the problem. Try this for example
 -(Δ^2 - 3 ga^2 - gb^2)^2 - Δ δa + δa^2 + Δ δb + δa δb + δb^2+(Δ δa+1)^3

Comment: @user1436011, you can  `Expand` or `ExpandAll` the input expression: `DeleteCases[ _?(FreeQ[\CapitalDelta]])]@Expand[expr2]` or `DeleteCases[ _?(FreeQ[\[CapitalDelta]])]@ExpandAll[expr2]`

Comment: @kglr :Thanks for helping. Still for the following term, for example, it does not work
 (2 + Δ g + 9 Δ g^2 - 
    3 Δ^2 δa + 3 g^2 δa- 
    18 g^2 δa Sqrt[(4 (-Δ^2 - 3 g^3 - 
           3 g +Δ δa - δa +
Δδb+ δbδa - δa)^3)])^(1/3);

Comment: @kglr. The problem is that Mathematica cannot expand this exp3 completely. So, I do not know what the output should be. However, I expect to see only thoes terms that contain  \\[CapitalDelta]. When I run the above program, some terms without \\[CapitalDelta] remain in the output. For example the term 2+3g^2 δa  is also in the output.

Comment: @kglr , It works. Thanks a lot. I do appreciate your help.

Comment: @user1436011, my pleasure. Welcome to mma.se.

Answer (score 0):

It might be even more concise to do something like this:

```
expr[[First/@Position[expr,\[CapitalDelta]]]]
```

Comment: Thanks, however, if I use a more complicated term it does not work. Not sure what is the problem. Try this for example
(2 + Δ g + 9 Δ g^2 - 3 Δ^2 δa + 3 g^2 δa- Sqrt[4 (-Δ^2 - 3 g^3 - 3 g +Δ δa - δa + Δδb+ δbδa - δa)^3])^(1/3);

Comment: That is a different problem. Your original question concerned terms as part of an expanded sum. This new example is about terms within an expression that cannot be expanded. As a result, this is feeling like subject-creep. It might be helpful to know more about what it is you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I am new to Mathematica. Initially I thought the same code can be used for both terms.